# Simile Timeline change order of lines

Tags: timeline, simile

How do I change the vertical order of event lines in Simile Timeline? Where in the code does it decide what order to put them in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried looking into this also. I am convinced it is random order.

This not the answer you wanted but try using this timeline

http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/timeline.html
It is quite flexible, you can choose your create your own layout and use your own CSS/HTML in each individual event.

Edit: Found a attribute that you could use to change the order

> trackNum - used to override the automatic layout of events on the
>   Timeline.

check this wiki for more info: http://simile-widgets.org/wiki/Timeline_EventSources

under "Event Attributes for Developers"

Comment: Thanks. I found out it's not random order. It uses the findFreeTrack function to look for the first available track where it wouldn't overlap.